# Any way to mix 'push' and 'over' modes of Angular Material mat-sidenav?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

Please check the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidenav-mixedpushover

I would like to set up an angular material sidenav so that it has a toggle button that is always visible and slides with the sidenav as it opens and closes. The main content area should be obscured by both the button and the sidenav when it is open (i.e. mode="over").

Basically I want the sidenav to operate in "over" mode but to "push" the button that toggles it.

I have tried several approaches but nothing works quite right. My current implementation (not shared because it's too hard to make a simple example of) has two toggle buttons: one that is positioned at the edge of the screen which is shown/hidden manually, and another button that is part of the sidenav content itself. If you squint, it almost behaves like a single button that slides with the sidenav! I also used some animations to try to blend the two buttons a bit, but it is very hard to match the speed of the sidenav.

Some pictures of what I am trying to do.

**Sidenav is closed:**

[image: Sidenav is closed]

**Sidenav is open:**

[image: Sidenav is open]

Does anybody have any workable suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem ?

Comment: @Alexis sadly, no.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution ?

Comment: Still looking for a solution, yes.

Comment: Ok let me create a stackblitz and I post a solution

Comment: The solution I provided is working for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you just want to see the result, go to the end of the answer*

The main thing to do is to disjoint the toggle button from the `sidenav`.

**HTML**

```
<p><button [ngClass]="{'button':true,'open':opened}" (click)="toggle()">Open</button></p>

<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav" (backdropClick)="close()">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav (keydown.escape)="close()" disableClose position="end">
    <p>Sidenav content</p>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    Page content with "over" sidenav
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Here you got your button out of the `sidenav`, the classes allow you, first to place the button where you want - with `button` class - and then to move it when you open or close your sidenav - with `open` class.

The `(backdropClick)="close()"` and the `(keydown.escape)="close()"` are here to be sure that we move the toggle button even if we don't close the `sidenav` with it.

So the style for this is this

**CSS**

```
.button{
  position:absolute;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: green;
  color:black;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  top: 50%;
  right:0;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition:0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}

.open{
  transform: translate3d(-200px,0,0);
  transition:0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}
```

On the `transition` effect, you see a `cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);` which is the transition used by the `sidenav` to display it's content. So with this transition used into our button, it will perfectly fit the `sidenav` moves.

And finally on your typescript file, you just need the functions to toggle your `sidenav`

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;

opened: boolean = false;

toggle(){
  this.opened = !this.opened
  if(this.opened){
      this.sidenav.open();
    }else{
      this.sidenav.close();
    }
}

close() {
  this.opened = false;
  this.sidenav.close();
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidenav-mixedpushover-aq8tgz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-example.css) you can see a working stackblitz.

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks like it will do exactly what I need, and once I get a chance to try it myself (in a few days, most likely) I will confirm success by flagging this as the answer

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to tell me if something is not working

Comment: I just tried this out, and it works beautifully! the cubic-bezier transition is a perfect match. I had attempted a moving button before, but could never get it to match the sidenav properly so I gave up on that approach. Turns out I was kind of on the right track but needed the proper transition. Your solution was perfect @Alexis, thank you!!

Comment: Yes this is the transition used by the sidenav, next time if you want to know how it works, just right click on your browser and click on 'Inspect element', this way you will have access to the html, css and javascript of the current page, but I am sre you already knew it ^^. So with this it's easy to find the transition ;) Glad it can help you.

Comment: I did dig around in the rendered html and css, but couldn't find the exact transition, so I wasn't sure if it was doing some weird angular animation trick or something. Nice to know the transition is pure CSS which I could have found if I had looked further :-) Thanks again!